# python: nested unwrapping in list-comprehension

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I am trying to achieve this in list comprehension

```
for y in range(depth):  # this one works
    mylist+=[x for x in s[y]]
```

This needs help:

```
# s= [set() for _ in range(depth)] # or list of sets
mylist=[x for x in s[y] for y in range(depth)]
> y undefined (error - apologize for inexact error message)
```

Is it possible to achieve this in list-comprehension?

Main question ends here.

---

More on the errors,

Instead of syntax error, I also get `name y not defined`.

So I tried `y=0` before the list-comprehension. And it worked! No more name error. Except, it wasn't printing out the content of the list, but rather some loopy numbers.

Even tho, what I am trying to do is violating something, python also seems to be acting strangely. Probably a bug.

Comment: It is copying-mistake. Works on my computer with proper colon. But my main problem and question remains. Please see my edited post.

Comment: *though the loops are in wrong order in your list-comprehension*

Comment: Your list comprehension sample does not raise a `SyntaxError` exception; as Ashwini has been trying to point out, the only error there is that you got the order of `for` loops mixed up.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks for pointing it out. I got what he is trying to say now. I got the error messages messed up while I was trying drifferent things. It probably wasn't the 'syntax error' at that particular line. But it just wasn't because of the ":". Apologies for the confusion, Ashiwini, if you can read this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the following:

```
mylist.extend([x for y in range(depth) for x in s[y]])
```

The levels of a comprehension should be placed in the same order as the loop. Doing otherwise was causing the interpreter to see `for x in s[y]` before it produced a `y` from `for y in range(depth)`.

Comment: This solves my buffling errors and output. It was a weird 2 days of hunting down errors. Thanks so much!